# Losing broadcast between during Activity changing

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to know one thing about broadcast.

If I have two activities A and B. Also I have broadcast receiver which registers in onResume() and onPause() of both activities.
What if I'll get notification when one activity is paused but other not resumed yet? Will my broadcast lost?

And subquestion is can I use sticky-broadcast in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently in the same situation as you and working it out with **Sticky Broadcasts**.

According to the docs, Sticky broadcast will stay around after the broadcast is complete. So, if any Activity is in the pausing-resuming cycle (orientation change) you will be notified of these broadcast once you register your receiver in `onResume()`.

Be careful though with these broadcast because they will stay around "forever" if you don't dismiss them with [`removeStickyBroadcast(matchingIntent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#removeStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) and could catch them again if the activity resumes again.

Send sticky broadcast with [`sendStickyBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent))

Remove sticky broadcast with [`removeStickyBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#removeStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)).

Also, you need `BROADCAST_STICKY` permission on your Manifest; add it inside `<manifest>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, Andres. I little bit confused after reading this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f37e3549a5e1be66) especially the last post. The statement about need use sticky broadcast just for cross-apllication calls looks persuasively.

Comment: I read the same article during my tests with sticky broadcasts. As the article details, sticky broadcasts will be replace if the broadcasted intent matches action, data, categories and type. You will always have the last up to date broadcast if you leave these fields the same and change the intent extras.

Broadcasts are sent through all the system so you better attach your package name as prefix to your intent actions in order to prevent other apps to catch them. Example: intent.setAction([PACKAGE_NAME].update).

Comment: This was a valid solution at the time when this answer was posted, but the sticky broadcasts are now deprecated since Lollipop, API 21.